# Is it possible to apply destructuring to storing a class method in a variable?

Tags: class, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following render method that calls another method in its class:

```
render() {
   const isValidField = this.isValidField();
}
```

Is it possible - and if so is it a good idea - to use destructuring in this case to avoid repeating the method name in the variable?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
render() {
   const { isValidField }() = this;
}
```

Comment: Is `isValidField` the only variable you are getting out of `this` in you `render` method?

Comment: @nils it varies between components to be honest

Comment: Nope, you can't do this. Your example is a good use-case for getter functions, which can be destructured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a getter function:

```
get isValidField() {
    return true;
}

render() {
    const {isValidField} = this;
}
```